Is there a way to open the subscribe telegram premium popup directly in telegram mini app?
I use @telegram-apps/sdk-react to develop my mini app, there is a feature that requires users to subscribe to premuim to use it.
I want to open the subscribe premium popup like attachment after I clicking a button in my Telegram mini app. Does Telegram have such a function? Currently, I know I can open the premium channel link by utils.openTelegramLink('https://t.me/premium'), and user can subscribe to premium in the channel. But I hope to open the popup directly.


At the moment, Telegram’s Mini Apps platform does not provide a direct method to open a subscription popup

thanks. btw, can I open the Buy More Stars popup in my telegram mini app directly?
